# Understanding difference in behavior of square brackets in NumPy 2D array sub-setting

Tags: python

I am new to python and learning it from basics.
I have a 2D array (npb)

```
npb=np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6],
              [7,8]]);
```

When doing subsetting normally (without colon), then it gives output,

```
Input:       nph=np.array(npb[0][1])    
Output:      2

Input:       nph=np.array(npb[0 ,1])   
Output:      2
```

but when doing it with colon, it gives output

```
Input:       nph=np.array(npb[:][1])
Output:      3 ,4

Input:       nph=np.array(npb[: ,1])          
Output:      2 ,4, 6 ,8
```

i.e.,[0][1] and [0,1] gives same result whereas [:][1] and [:,1] doesnot. Why?

Comment: `npb[:]` is a copy of `npb` so `npb[:][1]` is just `npb[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two ways of indexing, although similar-looking are fundamentally different, although they produce the same result when addressing a single element of the array.

`npb[x][y]` is interpreted by Python as `(nbp[x])[y]`, that is:
- get element x from npb, then get element y from the result of the former. So, with npb[0][1]: npb[0] is [1,2], and [1,2][1] is 2. Here, you're treating npb simply as a list of lists. With `npb[:][1]`, Python sees `(npb[:])[1]`, so: `npb[:]` is a copy of npb and [1] of that is the 2nd item, which is the list `[3,4]`.

`npb[x,y]` is a special selector for `numpy` objects (and other similar things like dataframes) and it is read by Python as: `get (x,y) from npb`, where x says which row(s) to get and y - which column(s). Such a composite index isn't valid for most Python collection objects - it works only on things that are specially made to handle it, like numpy.array. Now (0,1) means row 0, column 1 - just happens to be the same as `npb[0][1]` that is 'element 1 from npb[0]', simply because of the way numpy stores 2-d arrays. However, (:,1) means `all rows, column 1` - obviously not the same as 'element 1 from npb[:]' that you get with `npb[:][1]`.